# Facebook Graph API to Post to Page not working on new server

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

So I have been using the below code on my shared hosting server and it has been working fine but now we have moved to a dedicated server but this script is not working?

The dedicated server has CentOS 6.8, Apache 2.2, PHP 7.0.14, MySQL 5.6 and does have curl installed.

I am using a permanent access token also.

```
$data['access_token'] = '{my permanent access token}';

$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{my feed ID}/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dec = (Array)json_decode($return);

$link = "https://www.facebook.com/".$dec["id"];
```

I cannot find any errors in the console, is there any way for me to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't force SSL on the old server but do on the new server so the below line needed to be added after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```